# HTML doctype rendered with Snap / Heist template

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, heist

I'm having issues with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-1.0.0.1/docs/Snap-Snaplet-Heist-Interpreted.html#v:render when trying to render a template. The issue only occurs if I have the following as the contents of the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
```

while the following content renders fine

```
<html>
</html>
```

So it seems to be something to do with the HTML doctype.

The exception that occurs:

```
*** Exception: 
Initializer threw an exception...
/home/chris/Projects/Haskell/pkgscrape/Snap/snaplets/heist/templates/compareForm.tpl "/home/chris/Projects/Haskell/pkgscrape/Snap/snaplets/heist/templates/compareForm.tpl" (line 21, column 2):
unexpected "/"
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Snap/Snaplet/Heist/Internal.hs:74:35 in snap-1.0.0.1-6iNEjVc81Z8CCk3FAMxZ8z:Snap.Snaplet.Heist.Internal

...but before it died it generated the following output:
Initializing myapp @ /
Initializing heist @ /heist


CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Snap/Snaplet/Internal/Initializer.hs:597:13 in snap-1.0.0.1-6iNEjVc81Z8CCk3FAMxZ8z:Snap.Snaplet.Internal.Initializer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example isn't valid HTML. I think you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</html>
```

The doctype is not the same as an opening `<html>` tag.

Browsers are really permissive, so they'll accept your version without complaint, but Interpreted Heist tries to parse templates into valid HTML, so it chokes on an ending tag (`</html>`) without the correct opening tag first.